# Lenovo ideapad stuck on installing grub2

Tags: grub2, system-installation, lenovo

When I try do dual boot Ubuntu with windows in my Lenovo ideapad 320 the installation gets stuck when installing grub2, with the same tasks relating to the kernal appearing again and again in the terminal drop down box. I mounted only / and a swap partition, with the installation booting from the /.

Below is the screenshot of errors

[image]

Comment: Please post the screenshot of the error message that appears again-n-again

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dYXtX. Tried to use newer ubuntu (17.4) rather than 16..4 but error appears in the same place, if slightly different.

Comment: give a try to `Ubuntu Mate` also